# Reset Properties. settings when installed windows form Project vs2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installshield

I have windows forms project with properties.settings variables built it in Visual Studio 2010 and make exe file by using install shield and when installed this project on PC first time the settings takes Default value but when I Uninstalled this project and installed again don't reset to default value.
How can I Reset to default values in settings after install project again.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I Uninstalled this project and installed again don't reset to
>   default value

Assuming you'd like to get the default values of the Windows form application after re-installing you have to do some steps explained in this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/194563/how-to-reset-a-windows-program-to-its-default-settings/).

Hope that helps...